# How to make web workers with TypeScript and webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-worker

I'm having some issues with properly compiling my typescript when I attempt to use web workers with Webpack.

I have a worker defined like this:

```
onmessage = (event:MessageEvent) => {
  var files:FileList = event.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        postMessage(files[i]);
    }
};
```

In another part of my application i'm using the webpack worker loader to load my worker like this: `let Worker = require('worker!../../../workers/uploader/main');`

I'm however having some issues with making the typescript declarations not yell at me when the application has to be transpiled.
According to my research i have to add another standard lib to my tsconfig file to expose the global variables the worker need access to. These i have specified like so:

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
          "lib": [
               "webworker",
               "es6",
               "dom"
          ]
     }
}
```

Now, when i run webpack to have it build everything i get a bunch of errors like these:  `C:/Users/hanse/Documents/Frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts:1195:13 Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'navigator' must be of type 'Navigator', but here has type 'WorkerNavigator'.`

So my question is: How do I specify so the webworker uses the lib.webworker.d.ts definitions and everything else follows the normal definitions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, in `compilerOptions` set this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        //this config for target "es5"
        "lib": ["webworker", "es5", "scripthost"]
        //uncomment this for target "es6"
        //"lib": ["webworker", "es6", "scripthost"]
    }
}
```

Web workers can't access to DOM, `window`, `document` and `parent` objects (full list supported objects here: [Functions and classes available to Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers)); the `dom` lib of TypeScript is not compatible and redefine some elements that are define in `lib.webworker.d.ts`

Comment: Do you have an example of how to set this up? I guess that I need two `tsconfig.json` files - one for the main part of the code, and one for the web workers, but that's only how far I can get.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. As soon as I include "WebWorker" I get the mentioned error about symbol redefinition. Doesn't matter in which order I list the libs.

Answer (score 29):

Using batressc' answer I have managed to actually get passing messages back and forth working, in a somewhat nice manner.

Adding to his answer with the libs, the Typescript code also needs some nudges to get working.

First, create a file to make the file-loader cooperate with you when importing. I have a file named `file-loader.d.ts` with the following contents:

```
declare module "file-loader?name=[name].js!*" {
    const value: string;
    export = value;
}
```

Next, in your `main.ts` import the worker using the fileloader:

```
import * as workerPath from "file-loader?name=[name].js!./test.worker";
```

This `workerPath` can then be used to create the actual worker:

```
const worker = new Worker(workerPath);
```

Next, create the actual worker file, `test.worker.ts`, with the following content:

```
addEventListener('message', (message) => {
    console.log('in webworker', message);
    postMessage('this is the response ' + message.data);
});
```

You can then send messages back and forth in the `main.ts` file:

```
worker.addEventListener('message', message => {
    console.log(message);
});
worker.postMessage('this is a test message to the worker');
```

I have gathered everything in a github repository, if someone needs to the full perspective to get everything working: https://github.com/zlepper/typescript-webworker

This repository also have a `webpack.config.js` to show how webpack could be configured for this.

Comment: Another, slightly different, solution can be found here: https://github.com/Qwaz/webworker-with-typescript
It uses 'worker-loader' rather than 'file-loader'.

Answer (score 7):

rasmus-hansen's solution doesn't, in its base form, allow workers to import modules themselves. After some more digging around, I found that the example in https://github.com/Qwaz/webworker-with-typescript does. I tested the version in `worker-loader`, and was able to trivially add a simple module than can be imported by both `worker.ts` and `entry.ts`.

Answer (score 3):

Since I migrated to `file-loader": "5.0.2"`,

I got this issue : the worker file was returing

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and the url was `/[object%20Module]`.

To solve it replace the workerPath in the `main.ts` by

```
import workerPath from "file-loader?name=[name].js!./search.worker";
```

Comment: Thanks, gone around in circles trying everyone elses answer until I got down here (currently the bottom of the page), and it worked!

Comment: This is no longer the suggested way of doing web workers in Webpack 5.  [This page](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/) says you can just write `new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));` and as long as you have an entry point for the worker source (so it winds up in the output directory), it should just work, without invoking any loader directly.