# Angular 2 webworkers

Tags: angular, web-worker

All the articles and guides I could find about webworkers in angular 2 focus on making the entire application run inside the weborker. Is it possible to create just a single service utilizing webworkers?

Going by the classical example of webworkers, could someone show me how to create a service that calculates the factorial of the number using webworkers?

Comment: I have your same problem. The examples in internet use are confusing and beta versions of angular (before implementation of ngModule)

Comment: I found this simple example https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/tree/master/components/web-workers which uses ngModule.

Comment: Link above is outdated. Probably connected to https://github.com/thelgevold/angular-2-samples/tree/master/src/apps/shared-components/web-workers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Version**

Based on the solution that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715001/how-to-make-web-workers-with-typescript-and-webpack), I have build a simple class that use a WebWorker to complete his tasks.

You neet 3 files to have an working Worker.

1. **file-loader.d.ts** - need to load WebWorker files

   ```
   declare module "file-loader?name=[name].js!*" {
     const value: string;
     export = value;
   }
   ```
2. **background-worker.ts** - class avaliable in your application

   ```
   import * as workerPath from "file-loader?name=[name].js!./web-worker-example";


   class BackgroundWorker {

       constructor() {
           let worker = new Worker(workerPath);
           worker.onmessage = this.handleMessage;
           worker.postMessage('Caller: Help Me for background Work');

           // Message content can contain only Javascript Objects
           //
           // For Documentation:
           // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage
           //
       }

       private handleMessage( this: Worker, message: MessageEvent ) {

           console.log( message.data );

           switch( message.data ) {
           case 'Worker: Working':
               // ... Something To Do ...
               break;
           case 'Worker: Ok, I will Do It':
               // ... Something To Do ...
               break;
           case 'Worker: No, I can not':
               // ... Something To Do ...
               break;
           case 'Worker: Done':
               this.terminate();
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. **web-worker-example.ts**

   ```
   // ****************************************************************** Worker Bridge
   // self is a keyword: Reference to this Worker 
   self.onmessage = bridge;

   function bridge( message: MessageEvent ) {
       HandleWork( message.data );
       CallBack('Done');
       // use:
       //       self.close();
       // if you need to terminate worker from Worker Environment.
   }

   function CallBack( message: string ) {
       self.postMessage('Worker: ' + message, undefined);
   }

   // ****************************************************************** Worker Body
   function HandleWork( workTask: string ) {
       if( workTask == 'Caller: Help Me for background Work' ) {
           CallBack('Ok, I will Do It');

           DoVeryComplexWork();
           return;
       }

       CallBack('No, I can not');
   }

   function DoVeryComplexWork() {

       // ... Something To Do ...

       // Example:
       for( let i: number = 0; i < 1000000000; i++ ) {
           if( i % 100000000 == 0 ) {
               CallBack('Working');
           }
       }
   }
   ```

To start Worker, just instantiate worker  `new BackgroundWorker()` and take a look at the console.

**Old Version**

I had your same problem and solved it by building a service that extends a class of WebWorker.
In practice the service work by passing to the WebWorker two things, data and a function that elaborate the data.

I posted an example on GitHub. All the required logic is in the Following two files.

[fibonacci-worker.service.ts](https://github.com/AlexanderPaule/angular2-web-worker/blob/master/app/service/fibonacci-worker.service.ts)

[worker.ts](https://github.com/AlexanderPaule/angular2-web-worker/blob/master/app/service/worker/web-worker.ts)

Take a look at **app.component.ts** for call methods.

Regards.