# Splitting a Web-Worker in several Typescript files in Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

I run some Typescript code on a Web-Worker using [the file-loader given on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43834750/9836316) and it works as expected in my Angular 6 app.

For a better readability and maintainability of the code running on the Web-Worker, I need to split it in **several Typescript (.ts) files**.

I already tryied using **require('worker!...')** or **importScripts('filename.js')**, but i didn't manage to get them work with a Typescript (.ts) file. If possible, I would prefer an integrated build system the same way we import a Service in Angular2+.

Any help would be appreciated,
Regards.

Comment: Are you using a build system like webpack/gulp or you are just using the main typescript compiler to create js files from ts files?

Comment: I'm using the main typescript compiler. I'll try using webpack/gulp, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I wish i could use webpack to import several Typescript files into the web-worker but with the command ng eject being currently disabled in Angular 6 I can't access webpack.config.js. I'm kind of stuck here.

Comment: @Verrick can you give me sample steps to implement web worker in angular 6. I am struggling for 2days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally choose to implement [platform-webworker](https://angular.io/api/platform-webworker) in angular 6 using [angular-cli-builders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-builders)

Solution explained here: https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/issues/13

Comment: That would be better to provide the solution in the answer rather than providing a link as per explained on [answer] section. Thanks for updating the answer.